# How to get the benefits of 10-bit video output mode?

Tags: xorg, xrandr

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. I have used a few tests such as [this](https://resolver.tools/product/8-bit-10-bit-visual-bit-depth-test-chart/) and [this](https://www.avsforum.com/threads/10-bit-gradient-test-patterns.2269338/) to check if I'm getting 10-bit output and it seemed like I was until I tested on an old laptop with 8-bit monitor & GPU.

It seems like 10-bit is emulated in players such as mpv or vlc. However on my current machine - which both has a 10-bit display and a 10-bit capable GPU - I've tried following this [guide](https://www.soi.pw/posts/10-bit-color-on-ubuntu-20.04-with-amdgpu-driver/) and have managed to get Xorg boot in 10-bit mode:

```
$ grep -i 'depth\|bits' ~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log
    "DSP" for depth/fbbpp 30/32
[     2.675] (**) modeset(0): Depth 30, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     2.840] (II) modeset(0): 10 bits per channel
[     2.966] (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 30, 10 bpc.
```

Yet, I'm not getting any improvements on the videos. I still have slight banding on 10-bit modes (which are supposed to be non-existent). The only thing I get now is a pink google chrome.

When I check the output on my monitor's menu, I get HDR is off, which is fine I guess, since Ubuntu doesn't support HDR.

What am I exactly getting when putting Xorg and `xrandr` into 10-bit mode?

Comment: the more bits, more the depth and how much colors can be displayed. there is not much difference between 8-bit and 10-bit color on old laptops.